# Apache rejecting connections (for high number of connections from the same ip)

Tags: php, linux, apache-2.2, lamp

I'm doing some load test over a LAMP server, but for very high load (high number of connections) tests the it stats to refuse the connections. What I must do for allow all the incoming connections from the same client?

This is the exception in the java Threads:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: How have you configured the webserver? How many client connections are you trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need to change the maxclients setting in your apache config file.

Documentation is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#maxclients

and keep in mind that if you want to push the limit above 256 clients, you need to edit the HARD_SERVER_LIMIT

Answer (score -1):

It appears that apache can hold so many conection at the same time, so it starts reject some of them, which it can't coupe with. And it doesn't depend whether they are from 1 IP or not.